# Drupal 7 - What is the most appropriate way to retrieve all the rows of a particular column?

Tags: php, database, drupal

I am using the following code in an attempt to retrieve all the rows of a particular column in Drupal 7:

```
// Use Database API to retrieve current posts.
    $query = db_select('field_data_field_phone_number', 'n');
    $query->fields('n', array('field_phone_number_value'));

    // Place queried data into an array
    $phone_numbers = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

I thought this was enough to retrieve an entire column, but when I use the following line to display the query, there are no values to display:

```
drupal_set_message( '<pre>'.print_r($phone_numbers, true).'</pre>');
```

I know for a fact that there are relevant values in the table as I have checked using MySQLWorkbench.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Solved!

```
$phone_numbers = $query->execute()->fetchAssoc();
```

Should be:

```
$phone_numbers = $query->execute()->fetchCol();
```